# Scaling ratio in Android 3:4:6:8

Tags: android, mdpi

I would like to understand What is the scaling ratio for xxhdpi?

ldpi = 3

mdpi = 4

hdpi = 6

xhdpi = 8

xxhdpi = ?

Answer (score 3):

mdpi is the normal, or default. Its scale factor is 1.0.

ldpi = 0.75
mdpi = 1.0
hdpi = 1.5
xhdpi = 2.0
**xxhdpi = 3.0**
xxxhdpi = 4.0

You can get the scale factor of your current screen programmatically, so:

```
final DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
scale = metrics.density;
```

Comment: if i have 95*95 in the mdpi, What is the scaling ratio for xxhdpi?

Comment: 95*3 and 95*3? I'd say 285*285. but 95*95 looks strange to me. I'd prefer 96*96 (sorry, it's because of my professional deformation, to always look for **even numbers**, possibly **powers of 2** or anyway following a **predeterminate ruleset**)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually 2:3:4:6 in the order mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. You can ignore the ldpi density category. Here is the [Source of info.](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Comment: i have this screen for mdpi that is ok : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ybB5U.png but i have this screen for xxhdpi !!!! http://i.stack.imgur.com/uGBAt.png !!!!!!
How do I correct it?

Comment: make the dimensions for xxhdpi as 3 times that of mdpi.